# ABCjs misinterprets L:1

Tags: bug, abcjs

The two code blocks below should produce identical results. In Example 1 we have `L:1/1`, which renders correctly, displaying whole notes; however, in Example 2 `L:1` incorrectly renders as eighth notes.

For more information, see section "[3.1.7 L: - unit note length](http://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.1#lunit_note_length)" in the abc standard v2.1.

> Commonly used values for unit note length are ... L:1 (whole note) - or equivalently L:1/1.

#### Example 1 (works correctly)

```
X:0
K:none
M:none
L:1/1
[CEG]
```

```
X:0
K:none
M:none
L:1/1
[CEG]
```

#### Example 2 (works incorrectly)

```
X:0
K:none
M:none
L:1
[CEG]
```

```
X:0
K:none
M:none
L:1
[CEG]
```

Note that both work correctly in the [ABCjs demo](https://www.abcjs.net/abcjs-editor.html).